# How to employ a conversation within a CDI bean?

Tags: jsf, cdi

A page is requested by JavaScript with this url `pl_edit.xhtml?id=1`. It uses `PlayerEditBean` below. The `load()` method fetches player from the database. It works fine. The page contains a Save button which posts to the `save()` method shown below.

This is the first time I'm trying Conversation. I don't have a multi page dialog. I'm just hoping that the Conversation can preserve the state of `playerEditBean.player` for me. Unfortunately, it doesn't work. In `save()`, the player object is newly constructed with a null id.

Is there something wrong with how I'm using the conversation?

```
@Named
@ConversationScoped()
public class PlayerEditBean implements Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Inject
private Conversation conversation;

@Inject
PlayerService playerService=null;

private Player player=null;


@PostConstruct
public void load() {
    conversation.begin();

    // assume valid id is passed and we're loading a player from database
    String strId=FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequestParameterMap().get("id");
    player=playerService.getPlayer(Long.valueOf(strId));

}


public void save() {

    System.out.println("Persisting player with id " + player.getId());
    playerService.savePlayer(player);
    conversation.end();     
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to retrieve the cid param from the first call and send that along with the save call to tie the request to the correct conversation.

Comment: Any sort of fleshing out would all be pseudo code as the OP has made no mention of specific libraries or front end tech they're using.